# Reset identity column values after Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a temp table #jobs with `Rownum` identity column.

```
Rownum  Jobid   Jobname
    1   5074    Manager 
    2   780     Manager 
    3   71      Employee    
    4   654     HR  
    5   94      Employee    
    6   56      Employee
    7   35      Manager 
    8   81      HR  
    9   358     Employee
```

Now i am have sorting condtion on "Jobname" column

```
Rownum  Jobid   Jobname
    1   5074    Manager 
    2   780     Manager
    7   35      Manager 
    8   81      HR         
    4   654     HR  
    5   94      Employee    
    6   56      Employee
    9   358     Employee
```

My requirement is whenever I sort the table, `Rownum` column should be reset. According to order by I need to increment the `rownum` values.

I tried like below

```
  ALTER TABLE #Jobs DROP COLUMN RowNum //droping identity column from #jobs
    SELECT * INTO #tempjob FROM #jobs //inserting #jobs rows into another temp table
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Jobs //truncating all rows from #jobs
    ALTER TABLE #Jobs ADD RowNum INT //create a new column without increment

//now inserting records from #tempjobs to #jobs with ROW_NUMBER()
    INSERT INTO #Jobs
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Jobname DESC) AS Rownum from #tempjob
```

I thought this is good, but when large amount of records are in one temp table, i think its not good to use another temp table with same data .

Is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: if you would be sorting the rows based on different columns then why take the overhead of updating the column. why not generate row number at the selection time.

Comment: @Saksham: yes ofcource, i can use Row_Number(), but in my condition i need to update rownum column in temp table, i have different operations after this,in which i need rownum column.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a kind of simpler way. Try this

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP AS SELECT * FROM JOBS;
DROP TABLE JOBS;
CREATE TABLE JOBS AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY JOBNAME) ROWNUM,JOBID,JOBNAME FROM TEMP;
```

It will be a overhead when you repeatedly alter a table.
I dont say it's much efficient operation but it will be efficient than what you are doing now.
Please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

A much simple way would be to simply update the table's `rownum` column

```
UPDATE #Jobs
SET RowNum= ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Jobname DESC)
```